# Broadcast get to all shards in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using routing when indexing documents. In some cases it would be handy to perform a get without a routing parameter and have it broadcast like a search. 
I could not find any documentation on how to do it except

> Note, issuing a get without the correct routing, will cause the
>   document not to be fetched.

For comparison, the search API specifies:

> When executing a search, it will be broadcast to all the index/indices
>   shards (round robin between replicas). Which shards will be searched
>   on can be controlled by providing the routing parameter

Is it supported or is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: you could probably use the [id's filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-filter.html) to achieve this but not sure if it is an acceptable workaround for your use-case